# Auth0 component failure to compile

Tags: auth0, auth0-connection

I'm attempting to follow a tutorial with what appears to be the exact same code for the Auth0 component that will be calling Auth0 to do authorization.

'''

```
import auth0 from "auth0-js";

function Auth () {
    auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
        audience: "dev-pe-mju0a.us.auth0.com/userinfo",
        responseType: "token id_token",
        scope: "openid"
    })

    constructor() {
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

     login() {
        this.auth0.authorize();
    }
}

export default Auth;
```

'''

I can't seem to get past the compiler. Giving me parsing error at the constructor () {

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to programming and I've exhausted my capabilities!

Comment: It might help if you include a link to the tutorial you're referencing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want this to be a class instead of a function. You cannot put a property on a function (constructor() and login()) like that.

class Auth {

...

}